# Why is NetBeans running a previous executed file?

Tags: java

Although I have found similar posts to my issue, I can't seem to find a solution that works for me. The code is for school (not asking for help on that).

So I'm completely new to the Java world. I created a project which if I understood right, is a folder that holds the codes you work on??? Anyway, when I execute the code below it runs the previous one that reads (you guessed it) "Hello World". I don't understand why. Everything is closed. This is a new project.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculation {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a number for radius: ");
        double radius = input.nextDouble();
                
                double area = radius * radius * 3.14159;
                
                System.out.println("The area for the circle of radius " + radius + " is " + area);
    }
    
}
```

I will admit that I do not know what the files to the left are besides the project I created. Could someone please let me know what they think the issue is? Also maybe provide good reading on what the files on the left side of the picture are?

I searched the web for similar questions, none seem to work for this case.

Comment: When pressing the `Run` button, Netbeans asks you for the main class to execute. You can choose Netbenas to remember that choice. So if that is still in there, the project will run that class per default, unless you select `Run File`. In case of several projects open, Netbeans will be smart about what you selected when clicking `Run` or `Run File`. But be aware this behaviour can be changed in the options.

Answer (score 0):

To run specific opened Java Main file, just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.